# Change the key name of array validation error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-10

Here this is my form input (array)

[image]

I'm trying to validate the id field of this array of objects.

[image]
The error message return the key name as **dummy_answers.0.id** i want to change this to **dummy_answers** (without the key parameters with it).

[image]

Here is my piece of validation rules.

Requirement is want to change error field key name **dummy_answers.0.id**  to **dummy_answers** .

Comment: this doesn't make any sense. how would you differentiate each input error then?

Comment: @itachi my form input field uses multiple select option, the error is for that input field.

Answer (score 1):

```php
 $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'dummy_answers.*.id' => 'required|numeric',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($validator->errors()->toArray() as $key => $error) {
                if (str_starts_with($key, 'dummy_answers')) {
                    $newKey = str_replace(".{$count}.id", '', $key);
                    $errors->add($newKey, $error[0]);
                    $count++;
                } else {
                    $errors->add($key, $error[0]);
                }
            }
            return $errors;
            // handle validation failure
        }
```

### UPDATE

Using built in Laravel helpers you can do st like this:

```php
 $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'dummy_answers.*.id' => 'required|numeric',
            'some' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $base_errors = $validator->errors()->toArray();
            $errors = \Arr::where($base_errors , function ($key , $val){
                return !\Str::startsWith($val , 'dummy_answers');
            });
            $errors['dummy_answers'] = \Arr::flatten(\Arr::where($base_errors , function ($key , $val){
                return \Str::startsWith($val , 'dummy_answers');
            }));
return $errors;
        }
```

Comment: ok this one good, but any built in laravel options available, so i can avoid a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Request we can validate with rule and customise message with the help of messages method.

```
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'label'     => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
            'latitude'  => ['required', 'max:190'],
            'longitude' => ['required', 'max:190'],
            'address'   => ['required', 'string', 'max:500'],
            'apartment' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:100'],
        ];
    }

  //specify your custom message here

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
          'required' => 'The :attribute field is required',
          'string'    => 'The :attribute must be text format',
          'file'    => 'The :attribute must be a file',
          'mimes' => 'Supported file format for :attribute are :mimes',
          'max'      => 'The :attribute must have a maximum length of :max',
        
        ];
    }
```